# Getting Authorization has been denied for this request in Fiddler with Azure AD

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, fiddler

I have created a ASP.Net Web API (.Net Framework) app with "Work or School Accounts" as authentication type. This automatically registers this API app in my Azure subscription and I can see it under ["App Registrations"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kM3B.png). I can see that Home Page Url is pointing to [localhost address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDafE.png). I can see that API is launching locally on localhost address. I then launch Fiddler to get access token from Azure AD. My POST request to endpoint `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<mytenant>.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token`. has following 4 parameters

```
grant_type=client_credentials
&client_id=<appid from Azure AD Portal>
&client_secret=<secret from Azure AD Portal>
&resource=<appid from Azure AD Portal>
```

I get a token back. When I decode this token, I see `aud` and `appid` as expected(matching appid in Azure AD). I use this token as bearer token to invoke API call by adding `Authorization: Bearer <mytoken>` header in GET request to `https://localhost:44374/api/values`. However, this GET call to my API is returning me `{"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}` error message.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `App ID URI` as the `resource` value when acquiring token , you could find the  `App ID URI` in `Properties` of api app in azure portal ,like https://xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/WebApplicationName . Web api will check whether the `aud` claim in access token matches the one you set in web.config :

```
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
                new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
                         ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]
                    },
                });
```

`ida:Audience` value in web.config is the allowed audience .

Comment: Yup! That was it! `resource` should match `ida:Audience` API config value. Earlier, my API config value was using URI `https://xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/WebApplicationName` and I was passing `clientid` as my `resource`. Both values work as long as they are consistent. i.e. use `App ID URI` in web API config as well as `resource` or use `client_id` as web API config value and `resource`

Comment: If the answer helps, please consider accept as answer , that will help others who meet same problem .

Comment: I am still receiving the same error. I have one Web App registered in which I have granted access permission to my Web API(this also I have registered) but using above solutions, still giving me same error. Just one thing, I am using client id and secret Key of my Web App not of my Web API. Is that correct ? Please help me as this issue has been escalated now. Thanks in advance!